# Hardware implementation of Data Encryption Standard (S-boxes /permutations)

Tags: hardware, hdl, lookup-tables, des

I am trying to implement the DES circuit and according to a lot of papers, the S-boxes usually is implemented using a SRL or LUT, i'm not familiar with SRL, so i thought i use 8 LUT, each one has 6 adress lines and 4 data lines ( the 1st 2 adress lines represent the 1st and last bits of the bloc, and the 4 other adress lines represent the rest which will define the column)

[image]

For example if we take S-box 1 (shown in this figure) 
[image]

Here is the table that comes with it

[image]

That's just for one box, it seems to me wrong, to do all of the boxes we have to write 512 lines. My first question is: is a LUT a hardware component? if so, i am using it correctly? and, is there a more appropriate implementation or representation?
My second question is: what does it mean hardware wiring? I found out that all the permutation function could be implemented using wire crossing, i didn't understand it. Should i make a wire for every bit?

Comment: What is your target platform (device) for implementation? Design for that, not some abstract 'hardware'. A LUT is a look up table portion of a logic cell in an FPGA, the size depending on the target architecture. There are FPGA architectures with 64 x 1 LUTs available, requiring 32 LUTs for 8 S Boxes. A simple DES implementation is around 4700 NAND gate equivalents, explain why you're concerned with the size. A permutation is connectivity (where wires are connected) not logic. How is this a [programming or software](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question?

Comment: Once you've chosen the target device for implementation you can write programs to express portions of your design in a hardware description language, for example [sbox_lookup.c](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvi7qvm7ph0gmiu/sbox_lookup.c?dl=1). The idea, to avoid inaccuracies due to transcription to an HDL (VHDL here), manipulating known good information algorithmically.

Comment: @user1155120 yes i have chosen the platform, i am using haskell as a HDL. No i'm not consered about the size, i'm asking if it is correct. And you're right about the topic, it has been a long time since i've read about asking, so, i'm not sure where should i ask.

Comment: @user1155120 Before writing a DES programm in C for example we should search for its algorithm, that's what i'm doing searching (making) the DES circuit (structure) , before using any HDL to write it. ( i'm a computer science student not electorics so i'm not sure i'll be able to understand if i ask in your proposal Electrical engineering stask exchange section) but i will see.

Comment: You could also look in the original IBM DES patents, where the algorithm is described as hardware. [US3958081 - Block cipher system for data security](https://www.google.com/patents/US3958081) and [Patent US3962539 - Product block cipher system for data security](https://www.google.com/patents/US3962539).  It's what the patent system is intended for - to teach the art.

Comment: Here's a [VHDL DES](https://www.dropbox.com/s/abjv929qo0kb90o/vhdl_des.tar.gz?dl=1) implementation, wherein VHDL is also used to communicate hardware design data. The IP, IP-1 permutations are 8 wires, PC1 is 7 wires, PC2 is 48 C and D register outputs, E is borrowing outputs from adjacent R register nybbles and P is a 32 bit swizzle. There's a PDF file in the doc sub directory describing the permutations and organization of the f function.